# Safely connecting and disconnecting internal drive externally

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, ac-adapter

I just bought an IDE/SATA-to-USB2 cabling system (not an enclosure) which supplies power from an external AC adapter. I intend to use it to finally image all the stray IDE hard drives I have so I can dispose of them once and for all; and also to read or burn optical disks on the rare occasion that I need to.

Is there anything to be wary of when connecting and disconnecting these drives? I'm thinking about what order to connect USB end to computer, IDE/SATA end to drive, and AC power to wall. The power cable does have an on/off switch, so would it be safest just to turn that off before connecting or disconnecting anything?

Comment: Connect the drive to the power and IDE cables of the IDE/SATA-to-USB2 adapter. Turn the power of the adapter on and treat it like any external HDD. You can connect and disconnect the USB cable to the PC just like you would with an external HDD. Make sure to unplug the USB cable and turn off the power before you connect the next IDE drive. Also make sure you put the drives on an ESD bag.

Comment: Thanks; maybe you should put that as an answer. Do I understand you right -- it's not sufficient to turn off the power on the cable and disconnect the connector from the drive, but rather I should unplug the USB cable from the computer every time also?

Comment: Yes, make sure to unplug the USB cable from the PC as well. For multiple drives it's more convenient using a SATA to USB HDD dock. This won't require you to unplug the cable each time.